# Can i Translate the terms of use recaptcha when i hide the badge?

Tags: recaptcha, translate

When we hide the ReCaptcha badge, we have to put the terms of use and Google links in the form. Can I translate this text and Does Google accept?

Orginal:

```
This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google 
    <a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a> and
    <a href="https://policies.google.com/terms">Terms of Service</a> apply.
```

Can i translate to:

```
این سایت توسط ریکپچا و گوگل محافظت می شود
     <a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy "> خط مشی رازداری </a> و
     <a href="https://policies.google.com/terms"> شرایط خدمات </a> اعمال می شود.
```

Comment: it's a good question

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-hide-the-recaptcha-badge.-what-is-allowed